# Azure .mp4 upload fails

Tags: php, laravel, azure, web-config, mime-types

Good Morning,

We have setup a Laravel project on an Azure App Service. Were working on the ability to upload .mp4 files. If we try to upload .zip, .jpg, .doc etc they all work without fail. The .mp4 files though always give a error. Most of the answers we've found say its the web.config but we think its correct. Heres some info:

**Error we get:** 404 Not Found: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

**My web.config file location is:** D:\home\site\wwwroot\public\web.config

**My upload directory is:** D:\home\site\wwwroot\public\test

**My web.config looks like:**

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
      <add name="PHP71_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.1\php-cgi.exe"
        resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT,PATCH,OPTION" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
        preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As you can see we have the mimeMap in there. We've tried both application/octet-stream and video/mp4. Anyone have any thoughts/ideas? We tried placing the web.config in other folders as well with the same issue.

One other thing I tried was going into Kodu and manually uploading the file through there. It worked but if you try to access the .mp4 it shows the same error as when I'm trying to upload through the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the .mp4 file size bigger than 8MB? if so, you need to increase file upload size limits.

Create a file called `.user.ini` with the following content and place it into your root directory.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2048M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 2048M
```

If file size bigger than 30MB, you also need to add this to the `web.config` file.

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      <!--Byte in size, increase it to 2GB-->
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: We changed the ini file settings. We are testing with a file thats 30 meg right now. I'll add that to the web.config and see if that helps any!

Comment: You sir are a genius! We've been messing with this for 2+ days now and couldn't find anything on the web about it. Looks like we were just missing the requestLimits piece.